# Serving tensorflow model trained with files

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

Curious if anyone has the similar use cases as mine:

My tensor flow model is trained with tfrecord files and [queue runner](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/reading_data#creating_threads_to_prefetch_using_queuerunner_objects). As such the graph does not use placeholders.

Now how can I save the model and service it online? As during serving, we need feed the requested data into the graph. If there is no placeholder, then we have no place to feed.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the tf.estimator framework?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `TensorFlow` accept a `Tensor` use as a `placeholder`, for example:

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(10, dtypes=tf.int32)
a = q.dequeue()
w = tf.constant(2)
c = a * w
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(c, feed_dict={a:1})
```

So the input does not have to be a `placeholder` when exporting model, you can make any tensor after dequeue as input for your Serving.